# How Do I Hard Reset a Scene In Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a solution for how to hard reset a scene. For context, I'm making a game where when you die, you should be able to press respawn. I have the following code for this:

```
public void startGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    Movement.OnLoad();
}
```

Basically, the current scene the player is in is called "Game" and I want to restart the game scene if that makes sense. It's not restarting everything in the scene, for example, everything inside of the player script.

I tried to use an async to restart the scene, but unfortunately, it had the same result, I also tried going back to the start screen and going back to the game, but no luck

Comment: Are you using `DontDestroyOnLoad` anywhere? That is specifically used to keep things across scene loads.

Comment: Or is player from another scene even?